# Put in time + (infinitive / gerund)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I am wondering which sentence below is more correct grammatically and why?

> - You should put in more time.........

I failed the exam dad!
Pity, but it’s OK! Just you should put in more time........

**a)** studying 
**b)** for studying 
**c)** to study

To me, they all are correct and I think there should be a matter of personal preference. Though, this is what I think.
Please let me know about it.

Comment: "Just you should put in more time" sounds a bit strange and non-fluent.  It would sound more natural to say "You should just put in more time" or simply "Just put in more time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bare gerund **studying** is the only correct answer. "Put in more time + object" requires only a gerund.

You might say:

- You should *devote* more time **to studying**
- You should *set aside* more time **to study**

But the phrasal verb "Put in" ([definition 3](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_in) at wiktionary) does not require a preposition.